# SharePoint 2010 - 404 Not Found

Tags: migration

After a migration from 2007, and navigating to the default.aspx page I am getting a 404 Not Found error.

I am unable to determine where this is coming from.  I have looked in the event viewer as well as the ULS logs but cannot isolate the cause of this problem.

Any ideas on how to locate this problem?
thx

Answer (score 1):

Dave - I see your other question also. Maybe this will address both of them. By default, SharePoint 2010 makes a page named Home.aspx the home page.  It is in a page library called "SitePages" which is kind of like a wiki library. You can pretty easily make any page in that library the home page. Since you did a database attach upgrade, though, I'm not sure this is what is happening to you.

When you did your upgrade, did you also do the visual upgrade to update your site to the new user interface?

Did you follow all the steps listed [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303436.aspx)?

Comment: thanks, I created a site from a template I created and it didn't work wiht 404 error, I only had to choose a home page to fix it, your answer helped me

Comment: Good, Bassel.  Glad it helped. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a missing/unavailable page layout or masterpage, which was linked in SP2007, but not in SP2010 anymroe. If one of those isn't available, you'll probably see the 404 message.